# Increment eq(i) setTimeout function jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, increment, var

I have a setTimeout function I am using in a wordpress loop, and for each post I am trying to increment eq(i). For whatever reason so, everything Ive been trying doesnt work. This is my code --

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    var i = this;
    var sNum = 0;
    var iNum = sNum + 1;
    setTimeout(function(i) {
        $('.postidf:eq(i) input').val("<?php echo $id; ?>");
    }, 500);
});
```

I basically need it to be +1 for each post on the page --

```
$( '.postidf:eq(0) input' ).val( "<?php echo $id; ?>" );
$( '.postidf:eq(1) input' ).val( "<?php echo $id; ?>" );
$( '.postidf:eq(2) input' ).val( "<?php echo $id; ?>" );
$( '.postidf:eq(3) input' ).val( "<?php echo $id; ?>" );
etc..
```

Answer (score 1):

use String concatenation to treat the `i` as a variable.

```
$('.postidf:eq(' + i + ') input').val("<?php echo $id; ?>");
```

or

```
$('.postidf').eq(i).find("input").val("<?php echo $id; ?>");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are in WordPress loop then

```
<?php
    $i = 0;
    foreach($all_results as $data) { ?>
      $('.postidf:eq(<?php echo $i; ?>) input' ).val( "<?php echo $id; ?>");
      <?php $i++; ?>
<?php } ?>
```

Here $all_results means your all posts in array which you fetch by WP_Query and increment $i by defining it $i = 0.

Comment: I need it to be jquery though